# Gridview paging doesn't work after export

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with paging and sorting allowed, which I'm exporting to an excel file as follows.

```
Response.Clear();    
Response.Buffer = true;    
string filename="GridViewExport_"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+".xls";        
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",    
"attachment;filename="+filename);    
Response.Charset = "";    
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";   
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
GridView1.DataBind();    
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);    
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.AllowSorting = true;
GridView1.DataBind();
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

After the export,  the paging and rowcommands are not working. When I click on a page index or a link in a row, the excel file is downloaded again. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `GridView1.DataBind();` after enabling paging and sorting. And move it after the flush.

Comment: Is that the only code?  Where is this code defined?

Comment: @artm Tried that too.. still doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the initial `DataBind()` happen for the gridview, in the `Page_Load`? You may have to show us all relevant code.